# Musty smell in old equipment

Tags: maintenance

I recently came into possession of number of old ham radio and a variety of old test equipment.  Items from to 1960s to the 1980s.  Several of the items have a strong musty smell.  What can I do to get rid of the smell without damaging the items?

Comment: You might find an answer on [LifehacksSE](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/search?q=Musty).

Comment: This might give you a clue: [badcaps.net](https://www.badcaps.net/index.php?pageid=causes)  .  Old components degrading and releasing their breakdown products.  You might have to replace the bad components if you would like it to work again.  This often is cited to apply to computers and HiFi, but can equally apply to any old electronics.

The smell _might_ be a poisonous discharge.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to hamSE! These recommendations from the [ARRL Forum](http://www.arrl.org/forum/topics/view/132) and [Telecaster fans](https://www.tdpri.com/threads/removing-musty-smell-from-an-amp.977574/) suggest activated charcoal, kitty litter, ground coffee (not used coffee grounds!), baking soda, sunshine (UV light) and dryer sheets as potential odor remedies. Warm, dry, fresh air and time are also important. What works best for you may depend on the nature of the odor and what you have on hand to fight it.

Did you know you can post an answer to your own question?! Once you've had a chance to try to remove the odor, please let us know what worked and what didn't.